# Перемещение закачанного файла в новую папку

Tags: php

```
<form action="1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="nf" />
<input type="submit" value="submiter" />
</form>
```

1.php

```
<?php

$rf = $_FILES["nf"]["tmp_name"];
if (move_uploaded_file($rf, "../tg")) {
    echo "TRUES";
}

?>
```

При заливке файла на сервер не создается временная папка для хранения закаченых файлов.
Вместо этого создается файл с именем tg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции move_uploaded_file нужно так же прописать название файла:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($rf, "/tg/{$_FILES[nf][name]}")) // ...
```

Comment: спасибо!Все работает